# How to tell if a post is posted, or just empty

Tags: php

Is it possible to tell whether the Post is just Empty, or Just hasn't been posted yet? I know

```
if($_POST['varible']!="") {
    $loginerr="";
} else  {
    $loginerr="Please check your entry.";
}
```

or

```
if(ifempty($_POST['varible']) {
    $loginerr="Please Check your Entry.";
} else {
    $loginerr="";
}
```

I just want a way, to tell whether the $_POST has been sent or not.

Comment: it's `if(empty($_POST['variable'])) { // do something }` or the opposite `if(!empty($_POST['variable'])) { // do something else }`

Comment: People... the word is **"variable"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$loginErr='';
if (!isset($_POST['variable']))
    $loginerr="Please Check your Entry.";
```

Comment: This seems to be the only one which actually addresses the question - if `variable` is passed as `""`, it shouldn't be considered unsent.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Not to mention the only one who correctly spelled the word "variable". Well, including myself, but that's beside the point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

PHP isset is used for checking the row exist in array. empty is used for checking the array value. So here we can use this two in if condition is better.

```
 if(isset($_POST['vaiable']) && !empty($_POST['vaiable'])){

 //Here all the condition is satisfied and the $_POST['vaiable'] definitely have some value

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

the syntax to check is

```
if(isset($_POST['vaiable'])){code goes here}
```

to check post is empty or not you can check by following syntax

```
If(empty($_POST['vaiable'])){code goes here}


if(!empty($_POST['varible'])) {
    $loginerr="";
} else  {
    $loginerr="Please check your entry.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(empty($_POST['varible']))
{
    $loginerr="Please Check your Entry.";
} 
else 
{
    $loginerr = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `empty` function in PHP

```
if(empty($_POST['varible'])) {
    $loginerr = "Please Check your Entry.";
 } else {
    $loginerr = "";
 }
```

OR the `isset` function

```
if(!isset($_POST['varible'])) {
    $loginerr = "Please Check your Entry.";
 } else {
    $loginerr = "";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//save it in a variable
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
//now check
if(empty($variable )) {

echo "The field was empty";

}
else
{
//whatever you want
}
?>
```